# iText PDF image partially displayed

Tags: itext

The image is not displayed correctly in my PDF (iText) when I access thru my Java code. 
It displays partially with the first half of the image displaying properly and the remaining half displays with a lot of lines on top of the image. (the images seems to be downloading very slow when other text show up fast).

I use iTextPdf version 5.4.0 jar file and I access the image thru URL (get the image URL) 
in my java code.

Please let me know why this happens. If you need any additional info please let me know and I can provide.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: How should anyone know why that happens?  You didn't apply source code,  no sample PDF,  nothing to go by.

Comment: We've solved a similar problem with GIFs in 5.4.1: http://itextpdf.com/history/?branch=54&node=541 See `GifImage`: fixed remote loading of images. GIF stored on a remote server weren't always loaded completely (of course: if you're not talking about a GIF image, it's hard to guess what's wrong).

Comment: Thanks. Will try that. But when I try to upload the sample PDF Stackoverflow says that I need atleast 10 reputation to post images. How can I upload the sample PDF?

Comment: Hate to say this Bruno, but I am seeing issues with image rendering for GIF's and I'm using iText 5.5.5. Only about a quarter of the image's left side is rendered. This seems to only affect GIF's with an alpha channel set.

Answer (score 0):

Im also faced Same issue, later we solved. Please find the below code, hope it will help for you.

**HTML FILE**

---

```
<html>
<body>
<font color="green">Test</font><br/>
<table>
<tr><td><img src="Desert.jpg" height="300" width="300"/></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Java File**

---

```
class PageWithRectangle extends PdfPageEventHelper
 { 
      public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
      { 
           PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent(); 
           Rectangle pageSize = writer.getPageSize(); 
           cb.rectangle(pageSize.getLeft() + 3, pageSize.getBottom() + 3, 
           pageSize.getWidth() - 6, pageSize.getHeight() - 6); 
           cb.stroke(); 
      } 
}
public class pdfTest {
     private static String getUrlSource(String url) throws IOException {
         URL webpage = new URL(url);
         URLConnection yc = webpage.openConnection();
         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                 yc.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
         String inputLine;

         StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
         while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
         {
             a.append(inputLine);
             System.out.println(inputLine);
          }
         in.close();
         return a.toString();
     }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File baseDir = new File(".");
            File outDir = new File(baseDir, "out");
            outDir.mkdirs();
            String k = getUrlSource("file:\\C:\\test.html");
            OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File(outDir+"/Test.pdf"));
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
            writer.setPageEvent(new PageWithRectangle()); 
            document.open();
            HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
            htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(k));
            document.close();
            file.close();
            System.out.println("\nSuccess");
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }

    }
```

**My Old HTML Code(Gave wrong pdf while generate through java)**

```
<html>
<body>
<font color="green">Test</font><br/>
<img src="Desert.jpg" height="300" width="300"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**Solution : give image tag under table tag**

Regards,
Praveen

Answer (score 0):

I also have experienced this issues using iText 5.5.5 and found the issue affecting GIF's with alpha channel set. Either remove the alpha or try saving as a jpg. This worked for me.